# Use Mouse as Position Sensor

Tags: .net, mouse, hardware, device-driver

I have project in which we are using a laser mouse as a position sensor.  For the proof of concept work I wanted to use the electrical components as is from a commercial 'off the shelf' mouse to save development time.  This way I don't have to do hardware design, driver design etc.

I would like to be able to grab the coordinates off the position sensor mouse while still using a standard mouse and keyboard for manipulating the windows environment.  This means I will need to:

1.) Disable the position sensor mouse for moving the cursor

2.) Be able to still use a standard mouse for moving the cursor

3.) Be able to grab the coordinates off the position sensor mouse

I prefer to program in .net, but standard c/c++ solutions are fine too.  I am not sure if this is possible.  Any suggestions would be wonderful.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 for that I wanted to create 'virtual turntable' by putting the mouse on top of the empty turntable and using the mouse as the speedometer for it :) - however, wasn't able to have 2 mouses at the same time in windows...

Comment: You would need to uninstall the HID driver and then install your own driver for the mouse that doesn't pass input to the OS. The reason is that Windows doesn't distinguish between pointer devices at the .NET level.

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple of links that might help

[using-two-mice-in-windows-7-dual-mouse-dual-cursor](https://superuser.com/questions/29432/using-two-mice-in-windows-7-dual-mouse-dual-cursor)

http://cpnmouse.sourceforge.net/